# SSL Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, postman

I uploaded my website build with laravel on ubuntu server and used Instamojo to accept payments. I have purchased SSL from Namecheap (PositiveSSL).

The problem is my webhook URL is not working. I tried accessing the URL through Postman and got an error 'Could not get any response'. The screenshot of Postman Console-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by failing to bundle the intermediate certificates with the server certificate. You will have *at least one* intermediate certificate that needs to be bundled with you server cert.

For more information please read the [Complete Tutorial for installing SSL on Apache](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9423/installing-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache)