# laravel api cannot be accessed via postman or react native client, but can be accessed via browser

Tags: laravel, api

laravel api cannot be accessed via postman or react native client, but can be accessed via browser

I made the url for the test there

https://apisahabat.kopnus.com/api/test

The url is not blocked by authentication, and can be accessed via a browser, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ou2U.png)

but when I try to access via postman it doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvXh3.png)

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is your SSL certificate, for some reason, PostMan is not recognizing the authority validity of your certificate.

In Postman, go to **File > Settings** and disable **SSL certificate verification**.

Comment: @fakhrurrazi For the postman ssl error, the postman console shows "Error: SSL Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE". [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409362/ssl-error-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature) may be able to help with that.

Comment: it's true, I just realized that the SSL certificate has expired.

thank you for the explanation